# YouTube like Ajax Loading Bar

Tags: jquery, ajax, youtube

Expecting like- http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/youtube_loadingbar_demo.html

I am working on Ajax loaders, Youtube like ajax loader has impressed me much.

Well before Trying this loader i usually used to load ajax loaders in this way-

**Whenever ajax starts, completes-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.loader').ajaxStart(function () {
                $(this).fadeIn();
            }).ajaxComplete(function () {

                $('.loader').fadeOut();
            });
            $(window).load(function () {
                $('.loader2').fadeOut();
            });

        });
    </script>
```

**HTML-**

```
  <div class="loader">
            <img src="../../Images/AjaxLoader.gif" /></div>
        <div class="loader2">
            <img src="../../Images/AjaxLoader.gif" /></div>
```

I was using images and showing and hiding them on ajax start and end functions.

Now i wanted to use youtube like loader-

For a simple link it was working fine-

```
<a id="clickme">Click me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").loadingbar({
done:function({});
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I am not able to use this ajax loader on every ajax start and complete function.

**I tried-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('a').ajaxStart(function () {
            $(this).loadingbar();
        }).ajaxComplete(function () {

            $(this).loadingbar();
        });

    });
</script>
```

I want this ajax loader to appear on every ajax request in application. How can this be done?

Comment: make a single function which servers all ajax request on your application then call the loader in that function once finish

Comment: @ArunKillu, I already have function that serves loader to all requests. Have gone through this way you are telling me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup defaults for jQuery ajax calls via [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

Like so:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
        if ($("#loadingbar").length === 0) {
            $("body").append("<div id='loadingbar'></div>")
            $("#loadingbar").addClass("waiting").append($("<dt/><dd/>"));
            $("#loadingbar").width((50 + Math.random() * 30) + "%");
        }
    },
    complete : function() {
        $("#loadingbar").width("101%").delay(200).fadeOut(400, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
});
```

Any subsequent `$.ajax` calls will use those defaults (unless it specifically overrides the values), so a loading bar will show up each time. You can see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/QfgJ5/1/

Keep in mind that if you're performing multiple ajax requests at the same time, this will interrupt the loading bar animation. You may want to consider generating a unique loader div for each ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

To set the ajaxStart for every ajax call on page, bind ajaxStart to document object:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {

});
```

Inside an ajax call settings, set the `context` as below:

```
$.ajax({
  //other settings
   context: this, //set whatever element triggers ajax
});
```

Then, in `ajaxSend()`, you can access the element which triggered ajax like below:

```
 $(document).ajaxSend(function (event, request, settings) {
  if (settings.context != undefined &&
     settings.context.length && 
     settings.context[0].nodeType) {
     $(settings.context).loadingbar();
  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried it and it was not working. maybe there is another technique of working with youtube ajax loader.

Comment: what did you put inside `ajaxStart()` ? Hope you did not use `$(this).loadingbar();` because `this` will refer to document now

Comment: I simply called `loadingbar()` function. `$(document).ajaxstart(function(){ loadingbar();});`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still getting trouble with this way even.